# How to build and use the Z3 API in C on Windows platform

Tags: c, mingw, z3

Must use the Z3 in C , check to make SMT2 . However , I am not able to compile test_capi.c already searched the questions and found only two questions , I tried to apply but did not work . What I'm wearing :

- Windows 7 32bit
- MinGW Windows
- Download http://z3.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest # README
- Download http://z3.codeplex.com/releases/view/101914 to test the code developed in Z3py online

I tried to compile using the line:

```
gcc -o test_capi -I ../lib test_capi.c - L .. /bin/external -LZ3 -lstdc -lgomp
```

But I have not found Folder `../lib` and `../bin/external` in the download files in other issue was used libz3.o also not found.

Sorry, I'm starting programming in C.
How do I compile test_capi.ce there any manual that shows the command and C language equivalent to

```
( declare - function s ( Int Int ) Int )
( assert ( and ( > = ( s 1 1 ) 1 ) ( < = ( s 1 1 ) 4 ) ) )
( assert ( distinct ( 1 s 1 ) ( s 1 2 ) ( 3 s 1 ) ( s 1 4 ) ) ) ( check- sat) and (get -model ) .
```

Thank you for your attention and help.

Comment: "But I have not found Folder ../lib " - you have to compile the library yourself before you could use it.